# In a Xamarin Forms Android, what's the purpose of a styles.css in the Assets folder and how is it even used / called?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to clean up code in my Android app and I find the styles.css file sitting there.

Can anyone tell me, what the purpose of this is and how is it used?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This styles.css is styling visual elements file using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). A style sheet can be loaded and parsed with the StyleSheet class before being added to a ResourceDictionary:

```
<Application ...>
<Application.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
</Application.Resources>
```

You could refer to the MS document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/

Download the soure file of CSS from the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-styles-monkeyappcss/

Answer (score 1):

You can put any file in Assets folder in Android to use it later in the app. How this file is used in yours (or someones) app is something that you or someone else should know. Probably some package installed it and you can find in their documentation what it is used for.